# Monitoring a S3 bucket and downloading any new files continuously

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Is there any way I can monitor a S3 bucket for any new files added to it using boto3? Once a new file is added to the S3 bucket, it needs to be downloaded.

My Python code needs to run on an external VMC Server, which is not hosted on an AWS EC2 instance. Whenever a vendor will push a new file to our public S3 bucket, I need to download those files to this VMC Server for ingestion in our on-prem databases/servers. I can't access the VMC Server from AWS either, and neither is there any webhook available.

I have written the code for downloading the files, however, how can I monitor a S3 bucket for any new files?

Comment: Your boto3 program executes on lambda function? EC2 instance? local workstation?

Comment: On an external VMC Server, which is not hosted on an AWS EC2 instance.

Comment: Can you make it clear in your question, how and where do you run your code.

Comment: "how can I monitor a S3 bucket for any new files?" depends on exactly how you run your app. Does it have any webhook, is it accessible over the internet, can you access the VMC server from AWS. Can you modify the server, access? There are no details in your question.

Comment: So how do you check at present if the file was uploaded? How frequent are the uploads? In the worst case you can implement regular pooling of S3 in your boto3 program. Every, lets say 1hour, a cron job on your server  lists S3 objects and checks for new ones, which triggers your app.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at S3 Event Notifications: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/NotificationHowTo.html

Comment: Could you please expand how S3 events could help in OPs situation if there is no access from AWS to the server running the boto3 application?